# How does superposition enables the detection and correction of a phase error?

Tags: quantum-circuit

In the phase error correction code for three qubits, why do we need to use the hadamard gate? Can someone explain this with math.
[image: Quantum circuit for phase error correction code.]

Answer (score 0):

The maths is, effectively, $HZH=X$. In other words, a system with phase ($Z$) noise, and conjugated by Hadamards, is exactly the same as a system with $X$ noise on it. So if you understand how the bit flip encoding (circuit before the first Hadamards) and correction (circuit after the last Hadamards) detects & corrects bit flip errors, then you understand how this circuit detects & corrects phase errors.

Comment: I know that part. But I wanted to abstract myself from bit flip code and understand the phase code independently.

Comment: Then the important feature is that if you take the basis $|\pm\rangle=(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$, the $Z$ operator maps between the two: $Z|+\rangle=|-\rangle$. This means that if you have an encoded state $\alpha|+++\rangle+|---\rangle$, a single $Z$ error will be detectable and correctable, effectively by doing a majority vote of elements in the $|\pm\rangle$ basis.